# To use the data from input tag in html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the data from input tags in html. The html code is shown below.

```
<form id="sizePicker">
Grid Height:
<input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
Grid Width:
<input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
<input type="submit">
```

The data values from input tags should be used in javascript code shown below:

```
function makeGrid() {
  for(let td_row=0; td_row < 6; td_row++){
    $(<tr></tr>).appendTo(<table id="pixel_canvas"></table>);
for(let td_cell =0; td_cell < 6; td_cell++){
      $(<td></td>).appendTo(<tr></tr>);
    }
  }
```

Can somebody please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. Get the values from the inputs and set them as the range for the conditions in the loops. Then add your create `tr` in the first loop, in the second one append `td` to it. After all append the `tr with tds` to the table.

```js
const table = $('#pixel_canvas');
const inputHeight = $('#input_height');
const inputWidth = $('#input_width');

function makeGrid() {

  const height = parseInt(inputHeight.val());
  const width = parseInt(inputWidth.val());

  for(let row = 0; row < height; row++) {
  
    const tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    
    for(let cell = 0; cell < width; cell++) {
       tr.append(`<td>${row}${cell}</td>`);
    }
    
    table.append(tr);
  }
}
  
$('#submitBtn').on('click', makeGrid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sizePicker">
Grid Height:
<input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
Grid Width:
<input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
<button id="submitBtn" type="button">Generate</button>

<table id="pixel_canvas">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strings, when creating HTML element (e.g. $('')) instead of raw markup. I updated the function from the question, so that it creates a table and returns it. You only need to insert it wherever you need.

```
function makeGrid() {
  var rowsCount = ParseInt($('#input_height').val()) || 0;
  var columnsCount = ParseInt($('#input_width).val()) || 0;
  var table = $('<table id="pixel_canvas"></table>');

  for(let td_row = 0; td_row < rowsCount; td_row++){

    var tr = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(table);

    for(let td_cell = 0; td_cell < columnsCount; td_cell++){
      $('<td></td>').appendTo(tr);
    }

  }
  return table;
}
```